# How do I automate form filling in MS Dynamics 365?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, dynamics-crm

I am having a go at using javascript to fill in a form and then save it in hopes I can use these scripts to set up test data.

On Chrome, I tried to do the following to edit an existing account / submit a new account. I can confirm the elements are definitely correct because the browser highlights them.

```
document.querySelector('input[aria-label="Account Name"]').title='Test Company'
document.querySelector('input[aria-label="Account Name"]').value='Test Company'
document.querySelector('button[aria-label="Save"]').click()
```

I can see that the field name changes for the account name but hitting save fails. In the case of the edit account scenario, it reverts back to the old name. In the new account scenario, it doesn't save the account successfully.

UPDATE: I am trying to fire off the change event after I have amended a field, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement you can use EasyRepro Test automation tool for Dynamics CRM. check below article to get started.
https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crminthefield/posts/test-automation-and-easyrepro-01---overview-and-getting-started

Please mark my answer verified if i were helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the [XRM Object model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/clientapi-form-context) for working with get/set values of fields.
You can create a js that you call on [Form load](https://carldesouza.com/dynamics-crm-javascript-save-load/).

Comment: Thanks B but those resources are more for development. I am a tester checking the frontend so I don't think those resources apply in my situation.